# Sharing session over subdomains cause session to be destroyed on visit

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I try to share the session over subdomains and the normal URL. In config/session.php I have `'domain' => '.workplace.dev',` , so now I have for example 2 URLs that looks like:

`http://workplace.dev
http://testing.workplace.dev`

When I login at `http://workplace.dev` the session start and works fine around that URL, but when I enter `http://testing.workplace.dev`, the session beeing destroyed.

Any solution to this problem? Laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the session cookie be available across subdomains.

You can specify these configurations in `config/session.php` to indicate that you want the session to persist across subdomains.

```
'driver' => 'cookie',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => '.workplace.dev',
```